# Editing a managed bean for XPINC, rebuild and error 500

Tags: xpages, javabeans

Greeting, brethren,

So I inherited this app (yes, XPages can be legacy now ;-). It is meant for the Notes client only and one process takes a convoluted route via what I understand is called a Managed Bean (the Code/Java design element).

The database resides on a server.

When editing said bean.java, I meet two issues.

1. If I test immediately thereafter, I'm greeted with an Error 500 that won't go away unless I close then restart both Notes and Designer
2. In *some* cases, changes made to bean.java are not immediately available. So far I haven't been able to characterize those cases. For example, yesterday afternoon I could no anything, nothing would bring a change to the Notes client. (Yes, I cleaned & rebuilt and autobuild is disabled). This morning changes are apparent immediatly (save for the quit/relauch bore).

I've tried to set `xsp.application.forcefullrefresh=true` in the app's Xsp properties but haven't noticed much effect.

What am I doing wrong ? What could I do to fluidify the modifying of a bean ?

Answer (score 0):

When working in XPiNC, after every change you have to close and restart designer. If I understand things correctly, it's trying to access class files that have been discarded. That's why whenever I've had to develop for XPiNC, my initial testing during development is on a browser, I would recommend this approach.

There are minimal differences in syntax, usually only encountered if manually creating URLs to files etc or using the bad practice "" to specify database location in `@DbLookup`. Wherever possible, avoid @Formula approaches, their performance is worse than object orientated methods (e.g. `view.getAllEntriesByKey()`)

It's the same for the bean. There are only two ways to speed up picking up updates - use a browser or use XPiNC on a different PC.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of testing in a (real, standalone) browser. I'll try that. Which leads to another series of questions : when rendering XPiNCs, what HTML renderer and what JavaScript engine are used ? It seems to be based on Chrome, but which version ? More specifically, would it be realistic to use HTML5 and ECMA6 features ?

Comment: It's a XULRunner component. I'm not sure which version of Firefox the current release is comparable to. I would not expect it to support much beyond what was standard in browser a few years ago. I doubt there is much activity on updating XULRunner, since IBM's approach for mail and application access seems to be focussed on IBM Verse accessed solely via a full modern browser, with Notes Client apps accessed via IBM Client Application Access.

Comment: Depending on your version there used to be a trick to make a small edit to the faces-config - even adding / removing a blank line and that would help with the refresh problem.  I want to say XULRunner was around Firefox 3.. but not sure.  Again depending on your version and fixpack they did update that at bit some point.